# Mongodb checking exist field in an sub-document of an array using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
//MyCollection like this

{
    "_id": ObjectId("62878147ee22b6220ffaee5b"),
    "title": "TEST32",
    "departments": [ ],
    "contractCompanies": [ ],
    "storageKeys": {
        "gDrive": "1e1H_O-094XesdjVrFAgEkDEMom_OrrCI"
    }
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("62878ce73fdf68aa16e82c1e"),
    "title": "MyCont!",
    "departments": [ ],
    "contractCompanies": [
        ObjectId("6285ebed34c9e58020fd337f")
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to checking exist **id(6285ebed34c9e58020fd337f)** in **MyCollection.contractCompanies** of an array using mongoose

```js
await MyCollection.exists({ contractCompanies: { $in: new ObjectId(id) } });
```

Comment: You can do a simple find instead. What's the error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error. It just didn't give the result which i wanted.
As you said, solved the problem by doing a simple find instead. Thank you :)

`MyCollection.exists({ contractCompanies: new ObjectId(id) });`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing a simple find instead.

```
MyCollection.exists({ contractCompanies: new ObjectId(id) });
```